# The 'min-font-size' attribute in 'amp-fit-text' doesn't works inside an 'amp-list' block

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

I have an `amp-list` which has some items. The text within these items, sometimes exceed the item height. To solve this, I'm using the component `amp-fit-text`.

This component increase or decrease the `font-size`, then, the text fits in the container. But this component can do an ellipsis, if I define a min font size. Works fine outside the `amp-list`, but the `min-font-size` attribute is not being followed. In this case, the text is being fitted in the content, rather than use the min font size and creates an ellipsis.

I created a fiddle to show both examples: https://jsfiddle.net/po5mwLka/2/

Comment: This may have to do with amp-fit-text not knowing what the content is. The amp-list renders the data in after page load and by that time amp-fit-text is done it's job. I could be completely wrong in this theory, but I have been working with amp-list a lot lately and have noticed a few things happen like that. Maybe try injecting amp-fit-text into your JSON variables and rendering it out as HTML (ex: {{{VARIABLE}}} - triple curly braces) to see if that makes it function as expected. May not though as the JavaScript has already fired that makes amp-fit-text do what it does.

Comment: @CraigScott Tks the comment. I tried and results the same :/

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug, can you please file an issue [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new).

Comment: Hello @sebastian-benz, I opened the [issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/17130) and I'm waiting the answers. Tks!